# angular mouse enter unit test is not working

Tags: angular, angular-unit-test, angular-test

I am trying to test a mouse enter in angular 4 karma unit testing, There are not errors but the mouse enter is not calling the method binded to the mouse enter event.

```
  <div class="contacts-content row no-gutters justify-content-between"
       (mouseover)="onMouseEnter($event)"
       (mouseout)="onMouseLeave($event)"
       (click)="click()"
       [ngClass]="{'edit': hover}">

  </div>
```

In the component class I am calling below methods

```
  onMouseEnter(event: any) {
    this.hover = true;
    this.elementRef.nativeElement.addClass = 'edit';
  }

  onMouseLeave(event: any) {
    this.hover = false;
    this.elementRef.nativeElement.addClass = 'un-edit';
  }
```

Testing the mouse enter:

```
  it('should mouse over show the edit options to the user', () => {
    const div = fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('.contacts-content');
    const event = new Event('mouseenter');
    div.dispatchEvent(event);
    expect(component.hover).toBeTruthy('true');
    expect(fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('.col-1').getAttribute('display')).toBeTruthy('inline-block !important');
  });
```

In my test I am trying to call the mouse enter event but the expected result is not matching. More over when I see the code coverage, The method is even not called.

ny idea?

Comment: Why not `mouseover`? `const event = new Event('mouseover');`

Comment: I can try that but the actual component is called on mouseenter so testing mouse enter

Comment: It will work with `mouseover`

Comment: I was able to get a mouseenter / mouseleave directive working using `debugEl.triggerEventHandler('mouseenter', {});`.  In my case, I needed to use `debugEl = fixture.debugElement.query(By.directive(MyDirectiveClass));` and the directive has `@HostListener('mouseenter') myHandler() { }`.

Answer (score 3):

Try with triggerEventHandler:

```
it('should mouse over show the edit options to the user', fakeAsync(() => {
    ...
    div.triggerEventHandler('mouseenter', {});
    tick();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('.col-1').getAttribute('display')).toEqual('inline-block !important');
}));
```

or you can use real mouse event attach to target element:

```
it('should mouse over show the edit options to the user', fakeAsync(() => {
        const div = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.contacts-content'));
        let event = new MouseEvent('mouseenter', {
            bubbles: true,
            cancelable: true,
            view: window
        });
        div.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(event);
        tick();
        fixture.detectChanges();
        expect(fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('.col-1').getAttribute('display')).toEqual('inline-block !important');
    }));
```

Comment: Just one note about this: `.triggerEventHandler()` doesn't need to be used with `fakeAsync()` or `tick()` (and probably not `fixture.detectChanges()` either but maybe it depends on what you're doing in the directive).